# Good methods to return pointers pointing to subclass

Tags: c++

Here is a design challenge I have to deal with.
Sub-class of Base has it's own specific functions that are NOT defined in the Base.
I need to design a method so that I can generate different instance of subclass based on the input date.

The input data `Data` as the pass-in parameter of function `FactoryMethod` contains some complicated logic that determines which subclass is to be generated. The problem of pre-existing design(i.e. FactoryMethod listed as below) is that clients have to downcast the return pointer pointing to base in order to call the functions defined solely in subclass. This method is problematic b/c in the current design, we don't know what subclass is created inside the FactoryMethod. I can only think about two potential solutions

Solution 1> introduce a type in the base which stores the type information of the pointer pointing to base. Is there a good example that shows me the best practice?

Solution 2> return pointers pointing to subclasses instead of base in the implementation of FactoryMethod. Again, is there a good example to show off this?

```
class Base {
public:
    ...
    virtual void BaseFuncA() {}
};

class SubClassA : public Base {
public:
    ...
    void SubClass_A_Func2() {}
}

class SubClassB : public Base {
public:
    ...
    void SubClass_B_Func3() {}
}


Base* FactoryMethod(Data)
{
    if (Data designed for SubClassA)
        return new SubClassA

    if (Data designed for SubClassB)
        return new SubClassB
    ...    
}
```

Problems: Clients of `SubClassA` has to downcast in order to call subclass function

```
SubClassA* ptr = dynamic_cast<SubClassA*> (pointer to Base*);
```

As we all know, if you always have to deal with downcast in your code then the design has a flaw.

**Question**> Is there a good book/resource where I can find a practical solution for this problem. In other words, the client of the code doesn't have to downcast the pointer in order to use the functions defined in subclass. For example, the factory method may return the subclass pointer instead by adopting boost::variant?

BTW: It is not realistic to put all functions into Base and provide dummy implementation in the Base. Even if you can do so, you will not be able to get real functionality provided by subclass without downcast.

Comment: If it is not realistic to put all functions into Base and provide dummy implementation in the Base, then perhaps your classes should not be related at all.

Comment: Having to cast is not necessarily a design flaw. I've seen multiple pieces of software handle messaging this way, where they always pass around a base pointer, each message contains information about its type so the receiving end can cast it to its proper type. Use of dynamic_cast however can hurt performance, if you have type information available in your code you can avoid dynamic_cast and just use static_cast.

Comment: @Nic, May you give me some implementation detail for this method? Book/Resource is welcome!

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. If [C++'s] polymorphism does not help you here, why have a class hierarchy?

Comment: @aib, the point here is that subclass inherits the feature from base. However, it does have some specific operations that have to been implemented in itself. By providing a dummy implementation in the base doesn't help at all. Because you have to downcast to the subclass first in order to call the real implementation done in subclass.

Comment: @q0987: Sure, here's a blog post I made regarding video game engine architecture. This post is very similar to multiple game engines I've worked on in the past, used in shipped game titles. http://nic-gamedev.blogspot.com/2012/02/game-engine-architecture.html . Using a message system you don't have to cast your pointer every time you want to call a function, you just send the message, which can do work, and also return information.

Comment: I think not, but is there a possibility of having generic names for the derived specific methods in the base, like Base::Move, Car::Go, Human::Run?

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is with a messaging system, here's a code sample of how game engines can handle performing tasks and requesting data through messaging rather than casting pointers to call functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <list>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct Vector3
{
public:
    Vector3() : x(0.0f), y(0.0f), z(0.0f)
    {}

    float x, y, z;
};

enum eMessageType
{
    SetPosition,
    GetPosition,    
};

class BaseMessage
{
protected: // Abstract class, constructor is protected
    BaseMessage(int destinationObjectID, eMessageType messageTypeID) 
        : m_destObjectID(destinationObjectID)
        , m_messageTypeID(messageTypeID)
    {}

public: // Normally this isn't public, just doing it to keep code small
    int m_destObjectID;
    eMessageType m_messageTypeID;
};

class PositionMessage : public BaseMessage
{
protected: // Abstract class, constructor is protected
    PositionMessage(int destinationObjectID, eMessageType messageTypeID, 
                    float X = 0.0f, float Y = 0.0f, float Z = 0.0f)
        : BaseMessage(destinationObjectID, messageTypeID)
        , x(X)
        , y(Y)
        , z(Z)
    {

    }

public:
    float x, y, z;
};

class MsgSetPosition : public PositionMessage
{
public:
    MsgSetPosition(int destinationObjectID, float X, float Y, float Z)
        : PositionMessage(destinationObjectID, SetPosition, X, Y, Z)
    {}
};

class MsgGetPosition : public PositionMessage
{
public:
    MsgGetPosition(int destinationObjectID)
        : PositionMessage(destinationObjectID, GetPosition)
    {}
};

class BaseComponent
{
public:
    virtual bool SendMessage(BaseMessage* msg) { return false; }
};

class RenderComponent : public BaseComponent
{
public:
    /*override*/ bool SendMessage(BaseMessage* msg)
    {
        // Object has a switch for any messages it cares about
        switch(msg->m_messageTypeID)
        {
        case SetPosition:
            {                   
                // Update render mesh position/translation

                cout << "RenderComponent handling SetPosition\n";
            }
            break;
        default:
            return BaseComponent::SendMessage(msg);
        }

        return true;
    }
};

class Object
{
public:
    Object(int uniqueID)
        : m_UniqueID(uniqueID)
    {
    }

    int GetObjectID() const { return m_UniqueID; }

    void AddComponent(BaseComponent* comp)
    {
        m_Components.push_back(comp);
    }

    bool SendMessage(BaseMessage* msg)
    {
        bool messageHandled = false;

        // Object has a switch for any messages it cares about
        switch(msg->m_messageTypeID)
        {
        case SetPosition:
            {               
                MsgSetPosition* msgSetPos = static_cast<MsgSetPosition*>(msg);
                m_Position.x = msgSetPos->x;
                m_Position.y = msgSetPos->y;
                m_Position.z = msgSetPos->z;

                messageHandled = true;
                cout << "Object handled SetPosition\n";
            }
            break;
        case GetPosition:
            {
                MsgGetPosition* msgSetPos = static_cast<MsgGetPosition*>(msg);
                msgSetPos->x = m_Position.x;
                msgSetPos->y = m_Position.y;
                msgSetPos->z = m_Position.z;

                messageHandled = true;
                cout << "Object handling GetPosition\n";
            }
            break;
        default:
            return PassMessageToComponents(msg);
        }

        // If the object didn't handle the message but the component
        // did, we return true to signify it was handled by something.
        messageHandled |= PassMessageToComponents(msg);

        return messageHandled;
    }

private: // Methods
    bool PassMessageToComponents(BaseMessage* msg)
    {
        bool messageHandled = false;

        std::list<BaseComponent*>::iterator compIt = m_Components.begin();
        for ( compIt; compIt != m_Components.end(); ++compIt )
        {
            messageHandled |= (*compIt)->SendMessage(msg);
        }

        return messageHandled;
    }

private: // Members
    int m_UniqueID;
    std::list<BaseComponent*> m_Components;
    Vector3 m_Position;
};

class SceneManager
{
public: 
    // Returns true if the object or any components handled the message
    bool SendMessage(BaseMessage* msg)
    {
        // We look for the object in the scene by its ID
        std::map<int, Object*>::iterator objIt = m_Objects.find(msg->m_destObjectID);       
        if ( objIt != m_Objects.end() )
        {           
            // Object was found, so send it the message
            return objIt->second->SendMessage(msg);
        }

        // Object with the specified ID wasn't found
        return false;
    }

    Object* CreateObject()
    {
        Object* newObj = new Object(nextObjectID++);
        m_Objects[newObj->GetObjectID()] = newObj;

        return newObj;
    }

private:
    std::map<int, Object*> m_Objects;
    static int nextObjectID;
};

// Initialize our static unique objectID generator
int SceneManager::nextObjectID = 0;

int main()
{
    // Create a scene manager
    SceneManager sceneMgr;

    // Have scene manager create an object for us, which
    // automatically puts the object into the scene as well
    Object* myObj = sceneMgr.CreateObject();

    // Create a render component
    RenderComponent* renderComp = new RenderComponent();

    // Attach render component to the object we made
    myObj->AddComponent(renderComp);

    // Set 'myObj' position to (1, 2, 3)
    MsgSetPosition msgSetPos(myObj->GetObjectID(), 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
    sceneMgr.SendMessage(&msgSetPos);
    cout << "Position set to (1, 2, 3) on object with ID: " << myObj->GetObjectID() << '\n';

    cout << "Retreiving position from object with ID: " << myObj->GetObjectID() << '\n';

    // Get 'myObj' position to verify it was set properly
    MsgGetPosition msgGetPos(myObj->GetObjectID());
    sceneMgr.SendMessage(&msgGetPos);
    cout << "X: " << msgGetPos.x << '\n';
    cout << "Y: " << msgGetPos.y << '\n';
    cout << "Z: " << msgGetPos.z << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to read about visitor pattern to avoid down class cast. Hope it helps.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Don't use factory method in this case. You have to change your design. Looks like you need other interface instead of your Base class, or you don't need it at all. Please describe you problem in more details, so we can make a proper design for your problem.

Comment: I have updated my OP and please see whether it makes sense to you.